# Wrong configuration for database in seetings.py or docker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm learning how to work with Compose + Django using this manual https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Here are my configuration files

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

When I run using `docker-compose up` everything is fine.

But when I run using `python manage.py runserver` I got this error
`psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`

Guess, I have wrong cofiguration

Comment: How come that `docker-compose up ` works while `python manage.py runserver ` does not? the former run that command too. are you sure web container starts normally? Where did you run the command manually?

Comment: @Siyu - guess, the problem is I run `python manage.py runserver` from my local. Maybe you can advise, how to use settings both for docker and local development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot set `hostname` in `db` service.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    hostname: db
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Tip: Don't use `runserver` when you deploy production server. Check [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/)

*The solution is described in comments*

**Edit)**

separate settings example. Make your original `settings.py` to `base.py` in settings folder.

`<your_app>/settings/local.py`

```
from .base import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

`<your_app>/settings/deploy.py`

```
from .base import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

So finally, your settings folder contains three python file. `base.py`, `local.py`, `deploy.py`

And when you run server with local settings, `python manage.py runserver --settings <your_app>.settings.local`.

Comment: @Headmaster Wait, you call `runserver` in your local? You can not run in your local because your database is in docker. You can not connect container by `hostname` outside docker.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: And what is the best practice in that way. Have different setting for docker and for local?

Comment: You need also publish port 5432 to the host

Comment: Setting a hostname identical to the service name is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in docker/django setup , postgres container is initialized but the engine is not ready yet.
You must wait for the postgresql server to start before running the web container.

You can do this in several ways , have a look at [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize)

```
dockerize -timeout=20s -wait ${POSTGRES_PORT}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you trying to run manage.py runserver on host machine. Error means, that you have no access to host 'db' from it (try ping db in console). There are several causes of this:

1. Your docker container db is down. Try run `docker-compose up -d db`
2. You are using Windows as host system. In Windows there is no access to containers from host, you must install postgres locally.
3. You have networking problems. Try `ping 127.0.0.11` (it's docker's DNS server)

P.S. Do you really want local Django use Postgres in container?

Comment: I have run command from `1`, but it doesn't help. Linux, and good ping

Comment: Is 'db' container running? `docker ps`

Comment: From docker compose it may be called like 'docker_db_1', if it is, you must use
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'docker_db_1',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}` in settings.py

Comment: Or use 'hostname' like Yongjin Jo mentioned